# Spacing between antd Image components in React

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using the antd's [Image](https://ant.design/components/image/) component since I want that preview functionality it has but the style isn't taking affect when I am trying to add some space between my images. They are just stacked together with no space. The same thing works when I use `<img>` tag. Any insights on how to tackle this issue?

```
<div>
  <Image style={{marginRight: "15px"}} src={image} />
  <Image style={{marginRight: "15px"}} src={image} />
  <Image style={{marginRight: "15px"}} src={image} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage AntD's [`Space`](https://ant.design/components/space/) component.

```js
<Space size={15}>
  <Image src={image} />
  <Image src={image} />
  <Image src={image} />
</Space>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `Image` component [API](https://ant.design/components/image/#API), the component doesn't take a *style* prop.

I would suggest using a wrapper component to apply the `margin-right: 15px;` rule.

```
<div>
  <div style={{marginRight: "15px"}}>
    <Image src={image} />
  </div>
  <div style={{marginRight: "15px"}}>
    <Image src={image} />
  </div>
  <div style={{marginRight: "15px"}}>
    <Image src={image} />
  </div>
</div>
```